# How do I troubleshoot mobile web application on iPad?

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari

I want troubleshoot my mobile web app that isn't working on iPad in Safari.  Are there developer tools that would let me do that?

I'm trying to stream images to Safari via web service. The error message is being captured in my javascript that tries to display images. Safari has a Debug console which doesn't show any errors.

I wish there was something like a firebug for mobile so that I could step through my javscript.

Update. Found this http://www.blog.cordslatton.com/2010/11/debugging-ios-mobile-safari-ipad-iphone/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Install Xcode if you are using a Mac and then use the Mobile Simulator. Alternatively there is a Debug Console option on the Device (You can enable it by going to Settings -> Safari -> Developer -> Debug Console)

**Edit:** There is an article written by GoDaddy which explains how you can set up a Developer Environment on the iPad including Firebug Lite: http://community.godaddy.com/library/setting-up-a-debugging-environment-on-the-ipad/

Comment: thank you. i found the debug console but it tells me that i have no errors. i wish there was a firebug for mobile

Comment: Possibly this GoDaddy article on setting up a Developer Environment on the iPad might help: http://community.godaddy.com/library/setting-up-a-debugging-environment-on-the-ipad/

Comment: found this. will try it and let you know. http://www.blog.cordslatton.com/2010/11/debugging-ios-mobile-safari-ipad-iphone/

Comment: That is the same article as the GoDaddy one I linked :)